# At least 2 letters and any number of digits and some special symbols in any order

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to write REGEX to allow **(in any order)** only letters, digits and few special symbols (spaces, hyphens, `&` etc.), but at least 2 letters, and disallow any other special symbols.

For now, I have this:

```
\A^(?=.*[a-zA-Z]{2,})(?=.*[0-9]*).*+$\z
```

but it accepts almost all special symbols. How can I improve it? Thanks.

Comment: You may use: `\A(?=(?:[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){2})[a-zA-Z0-9\s&-]+\z`

Comment: @anubhava, it works great! Write separate answer, so I could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex for your requirement:

```
\A(?=(?:[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){2})[a-zA-Z0-9\s&-]+\z
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `\A`: Start
- `(?=(?:[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){2})`: Lookahead to assert we have at least 2 alphabets in input
- `[a-zA-Z0-9\s&-]+`: Match alphanumeric character or whitespace or `&` or `-`
- `\z`: End

[RegEx Demo](http://rubular.com/r/3TnrlfiacG)

Comment: Help me again, please) All old requirements + "line should start with alphanumeric character"

Comment: Then you can use: `\A(?=(?:[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){2})[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\s&-]*\z`